# Qt: send QPixmap in QDrag's QMimeData?

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, mime, qgraphicsview, qlistwidget

I create a drag object from a `QListWidgetItem`.
I can send text as mime data in this drag object.

How can I send a pixmap and retrieve it from the mime data?
Would it even be possible to create a `QGraphicsItem` and retrieve it?

I try to drag & drop from the `QListWidget` into a `QGraphicsView`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways to send a `QPixmap` through `QMimeData`:

1. by encoding it into a file format such as PNG and sending that with mime-type `image/png` (`QMimeData` has built-in support for that, cf. `QMimeData::imageData()`).
2. by serialising the `QPixmap` into a `QByteArray` using a `QDataStream` and sending the serialisation under an app-specific mime-type `application/x-app-name`.
3. by writing the image data to a file on disk and sending a file-URL for it with mime-type `text/uri-list` (`QMimeData` has built-in support for this, cf. `QMimeData::urls()`). This allows to drag these images onto a file manager or the desktop.
4. similar to (2) above, you can also create a `QGraphicsItem`, stuff its address into a `QByteArray` and send that under an app-specific mime-type. This doesn't work if the drag ends in another process, of course (the receiving site can test, because `QDragEvent::source()` returns `0` in that case), and it requires special care to handle the graphic item's lifetime.

Seeing as `QMimeData` allows you to pass several formats at once, these options are non-exclusive. You should, however, sort the formats you return from your reimplementation of `QMimeData::formats()` in order of decreasing specificity, i.e. your app-private formats come first, and `text/uri-list` comes last.